# Selecting data in an Sqlite3 database-Python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

The code below i got as i was learning about Sqlite3-Python for creating a simple database. creating its tables and inserting data...

```
import sqlite3
db=sqlite3.connect('E:/CLYDE/sqlite new2/dbase.db')
cursor=db.cursor()
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE users(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT,
                       phone TEXT, email TEXT unique, password TEXT)''')
db.commit()

name1 = 'Andres'
phone1 = '3366858'
email1 = 'user@example.com'
# A very secure password
password1 = '12345'

name2 = 'John'
phone2 = '5557241'
email2 = 'johndoe@example.com'
password2 = 'abcdef'

users = [(name1,phone1, email1, password1),
         (name2,phone2, email2, password2)]
cursor.executemany(''' INSERT INTO users(name, phone, email, password) VALUES(?,?,?,?)''', users)
db.commit()
```

The piece of code (in the same directory as the one above)  below is mearnt to determine if a certain element (string) is in the database. What way can be used to determine this? currently its always printing no, for any item in the database.

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('dbase.db')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
all_rows = cursor.fetchall()
if 'John' in all_rows:
  print('yes')
else:
  print('no')
db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to go further down in your data to locate "John":

The type of all_rows is a list, you have to iterate through that list in order to make your check.

```
for row in all_rows:
    if 'John' in row:
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```